# Anyone understand this combinations problem?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Marcus is having a party.  He can purchase up to 5 bags of chips, 6 cases of pop, 2 cakes and 3 chip dips.  How many different purchases can he make?

What has to be done to solve this question?

Answer (score 2):

First you should look at the word "up to" this means that numbers given can be in a range limited by the number given.  So he can purchase 0 bags of chips, 1 bag of chips, ... 5 bags of chips.  There are 6 different classes of chip purchases.

You can then go though each option $ 6 \times 7 \times 3 \times 4$ to get all possible cases.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the purchases are different foods are independent, the number of possible combinations is $6\cdot7\cdot3\cdot4=504$ by the [Fundamental Counting Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product). The numbers comes from the possible number of ways he can buy chips, cases of pop, cakes, and chip dips, respectively. "Up to 5 bags of chips" means 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 bags, which is six possible ways. The same is done for each additional food item.

Comment: I think you need to include the scenario that he could purchase none of any of the items as Q the Platypus stated in his answer.

Comment: Of course; what an egregious error...